# Generic B-Tree to store custom objects/data types

Tags: c++, data-structures

I want to have a B-Tree, which can store any type of data.  Maybe even custom objects and data types.  For ex: I might store some integers, some strings ("ex: jack, jill etc) or even some custom objects (MyClass obj1, obj2 etc).

What I want to know is, how do I insert/delete/search the objects and maintain the Tree ? I can use the comparison ops for integers, but what about other types like strings, custom objects etc ?

I also want to know, what is the best way to go about designing my classes ? I can think of two options :

1. I use a class template and write specialization for each.  This is really cumbersome, and least preferable for me.
2. I use an abstract base class for the Tree Node with virtual get/set methods.  Each node will have a unique integer "key" attribute which can be used for comparisons in Tree ops. All my data types will *have to* derive from this class. In this case, I can write a compare() for comparing the keys.  One big drawback I see here is the maintenance of keys, which would need another ds like a stack.

Do let me know your inputs on what is the best way going forward.  Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Have a look at `std::set`. IMHO it shows how to solve your issue. Pay attention to: what operators are required for the data type to be used for the key values. E.g. the `std::set` has a template parameter for a less functor. The default argument is one which uses the `operator <` for keys. Btw. AFAIK, `std::set` uses a tree internally.

Comment: Btw. some advertising: In my answer to [SO: Preorder traversal through Morse code BST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45055152/7478597), I used templates for a tree (just for fun). In this sample, I could have embedded the class template for the tree node in the class template for the tree. Hence, the tree node class template would have become a class. I didn't do this to not confuse the questioner too much.

Answer (score 0):

in the node declare a void pointer like below. Where you can store address of any type. But while searching the tree you have to check for every types,

```
void* val;

node->val = pointer of a int //ok
node->val = pointer of a char//ok
node->val = pointer of a object including user define type//ok
```