# Binary search tree C++ need the search and display functions to work

Tags: c++

Need a void function Display that will display the binary search tree in tree shape

Need a value return or void function Search that will search for a specific data.

Not really sure What to do from this point except trial and error and trying to read off of others code...

I need help

Help

Here is my code...

```
  class BinarySearchTree
{
private:
struct tree_node
{
    tree_node* left;
    tree_node* right;
    int data;
};
tree_node* root;

public:
BinarySearchTree()
{
    root = NULL;
}

bool isEmpty() const { return root == NULL; }
void print_inorder();
void inorder(tree_node*);
void print_preorder();
void preorder(tree_node*);
void print_postorder();
void postorder(tree_node*);
void insert(int);
void remove(int);
bool Search(int, tree_node*);
void Display(tree_node*, int);


 };

 int main()
 {
BinarySearchTree b;
int ch, tmp, tmp1;

while (1)
{
    system("cls");
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << " Binary Search Tree Operations " << endl;
    cout << " ----------------------------- " << endl;
    cout << " 1. Insertion/Creation " << endl;
    cout << " 2. In-Order Traversal " << endl;
    cout << " 3. Pre-Order Traversal " << endl;
    cout << " 4. Post-Order Traversal " << endl;
    cout << " 5. Removal " << endl;
    cout << " 6. Display " << endl;
    cout << " 7. Display Message From Creator " << endl;
    cout << " 8. EXIT " << endl;
    cout << " Enter your choice : ";
    cin >> ch;
    switch (ch)
    {
    case 1: cout << " Enter Number to be inserted : ";
        cin >> tmp;
        b.insert(tmp);
        break;
    case 2: cout << endl;
        cout << " In-Order Traversal " << endl;
        cout << " -------------------" << endl;
        b.print_inorder();
        break;
    case 3: cout << endl;
        cout << " Pre-Order Traversal " << endl;
        cout << " -------------------" << endl;
        b.print_preorder();
        break;
    case 4: cout << endl;
        cout << " Post-Order Traversal " << endl;
        cout << " --------------------" << endl;
        b.print_postorder();
        break;
    case 5: cout << " Enter data to be deleted : ";
        cin >> tmp1;
        b.remove(tmp1);
        break;
    case 6: cout << " Enter data to be deleted : ";
        b.Display(NULL, tmp);
        break;
    case 7: cout << " I think you are a great person. Smile be happy ";
    case 8:
        return 0;
    }
    }
   }

  bool BinarySearchTree::Search(int d, tree_node* curr){
    if (curr == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }

   if (curr->data == d) {
    return 1;
    }

    if (d > curr->data) {
    return Search(d, curr->right);
   }
  else {
    return Search(d, curr->left);
   }
 }





  // Smaller elements go left
  // larger elements go right
void BinarySearchTree::insert(int d)
 {
 tree_node* t = new tree_node;
tree_node* parent;
t->data = d;
t->left = NULL;
t->right = NULL;
parent = NULL;

// is this a new tree?
if (isEmpty()) root = t;
else
{
    //Note: ALL insertions are as leaf nodes
    tree_node* curr;
    curr = root;
    // Find the Node's parent
    while (curr)
    {
        parent = curr;
        if (t->data > curr->data) curr = curr->right;
        else curr = curr->left;
    }

    if (t->data < parent->data)
        parent->left = t;
    else
        parent->right = t;
     }
 }

  void BinarySearchTree::remove(int d)
 {
//Locate the element
bool found = false;
if (isEmpty())
{
    cout << " This Tree is empty! " << endl;
    return;
}

tree_node* curr;
tree_node* parent;
curr = root;

while (curr != NULL)
{
    if (curr->data == d)
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        parent = curr;
        if (d>curr->data) curr = curr->right;
        else curr = curr->left;
    }
    }
 if (!found)
 {
    cout << " Data not found! " << endl;
    return;
 }


// 3 cases :
// 1. We're removing a leaf node
// 2. We're removing a node with a single child
// 3. we're removing a node with 2 children
parent = NULL;
// Node with single child
if ((curr->left == NULL && curr->right != NULL) || (curr->left != NULL
    && curr->right == NULL))
{
    if (curr->left == NULL && curr->right != NULL)
    {
        if (parent->left == curr)
        {
            parent->left = curr->right;
            delete curr;
        }
        else
        {
            parent->right = curr->right;
            delete curr;
        }
    }
    else // left child present, no right child
    {
        if (parent->left == curr)
        {
            parent->left = curr->left;
            delete curr;
        }
        else
        {
            parent->right = curr->left;
            delete curr;
        }
    }
    return;
}

//We're looking at a leaf node
if (curr->left == NULL && curr->right == NULL)
{
    if (parent->left == curr) parent->left = NULL;
    else parent->right = NULL;
    delete curr;
    return;
}


//Node with 2 children
// replace node with smallest value in right subtree
if (curr->left != NULL && curr->right != NULL)
{
    tree_node* chkr;
    chkr = curr->right;
    if ((chkr->left == NULL) && (chkr->right == NULL))
    {
        curr = chkr;
        delete chkr;
        curr->right = NULL;
    }
    else // right child has children
    {
        //if the node's right child has a left child
        // Move all the way down left to locate smallest element

        if ((curr->right)->left != NULL)
        {
            tree_node* lcurr;
            tree_node* lcurrp;
            lcurrp = curr->right;
            lcurr = (curr->right)->left;
            while (lcurr->left != NULL)
            {
                lcurrp = lcurr;
                lcurr = lcurr->left;
            }
            curr->data = lcurr->data;
            delete lcurr;
            lcurrp->left = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            tree_node* tmp;
            tmp = curr->right;
            curr->data = tmp->data;
            curr->right = tmp->right;
            delete tmp;
        }

    }
    return;
}

}

 void BinarySearchTree::print_inorder()
 {
inorder(root);
}

 void BinarySearchTree::inorder(tree_node* p)
 {
if (p != NULL)
{
    if (p->left) inorder(p->left);
    cout << " " << p->data << " ";
    if (p->right) inorder(p->right);
}
else return;
 }

 void BinarySearchTree::print_preorder()
  {
preorder(root);
 }

 void BinarySearchTree::preorder(tree_node* p)
 {
if (p != NULL)
{
    cout << " " << p->data << " ";
    if (p->left) preorder(p->left);
    if (p->right) preorder(p->right);
}
else return;
}

void BinarySearchTree::print_postorder()
{
postorder(root);
}

void BinarySearchTree::postorder(tree_node* p)
{
if (p != NULL)
{
    if (p->left) postorder(p->left);
    if (p->right) postorder(p->right);
    cout << " " << p->data << " ";
}
else return;
 }
 void BinarySearchTree::Display(tree_node *curr, int indent)
 {
if (curr != NULL)

{
    cout << "My Tree. The left is top and right is bottom" << endl;
    Display(curr->left, indent + 4);
    if (indent > 0)
        cout << setw(indent) << " ";
    cout << curr->data << endl;
    Display(curr->right, indent + 4);
}
 }
```

Comment: It is not displaying from the menu when the program compiles

Comment: The way you call your display method for "6", the `if` condition will be false and the method returns immediatly. That is why it is not displaying anything.

Comment: Some advertising: Please, have a look at [SO: Preorder traversal through Morse code BST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45055152/7478597). You find a sample for the display part of your question. Concerning, the search part, it might be extended appropriately (deriving a  new `BST::Apply` functor).

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: How can i call my display?