# Traverse function with generic function as parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary

I am trying to implement a binary search tree.

I find myself needing to traverse the tree for a few different reasons:

(1) To check if the BST has a particular element

(2) To populate an array of the values held in the BST

(3) To check whether or not two BST's are equal

Is there a way to write a traverse function that takes in as a parameter a generic function (whose parameters are not specified) in order to call that function as it traverses the BST?

(For example, a function that checks whether the value of the current node is equal to the given value).

Thank you :)

Comment: Why not use a [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)? `std::function` lets you stick any callable object (functor, lambda, function pointer) into a convenient object that can be passed around like any other

Comment: 1.) alter igel provided a link (which has also examples). 2.) Googling for `std::function` should provide plenty of examples. However, I once wrote an answer to [SO: Preorder traversal through Morse code BST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45055152/7478597) with a slightly different solution: an `Apply` class with 3 different access methods which might be derived for multiple purposes.

Comment: What about std::bind with auto: https://onlinegdb.com/ByWdwPBi4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take help of function pointers. Pass the function's address as a parameter to your traverse function:

```
void func_to_call()
{
...
}

// Call to traverse with function pointer as one of the arguments
traverse(&func_to_call, <other parameters required by traverse>);
```